# Sort list of dictionaries using dictionary key

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and trying to sort by key but couldn't get met requirement.
I'm new to python.
I have tried the following solution

```
sorted(data, key=itemgetter('key'))
```

```
data = [
          {
            "key" : "NEU",
            "value" : 49
          },
          {
            "key" : "POS",
            "value" : 30
          },
          {
            "key" : "NEG",
            "value" : 39
          },
          {
            "key" : "N/A",
            "value" : 10
          }
        ]
```

I want output like

```
[         {
            "key" : "N/A",
            "value" : 10
          },
          {
            "key" : "NEG",
            "value" : 39
          },
          {
            "key" : "NEU",
            "value" : 49
          },
          {
            "key" : "POS",
            "value" : 30
          }
        ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
sorted(data, key=lambda x: x["key"])
```

We create an anonymous function via `lambda` where our argument is `x` (the values inside of `data`) and then we return the entry `key` of the dictionary inside of the lists to sort the data.